# I have an array of 8 bytes and would like to convert it into a double. How can I do this within office libre basic?

Tags: arrays, double, libreoffice

I have an array of 8 bytes and would like to convert it into a double.  How can I do this within LibreOffice Basic?

More info: the 8 byte array is declared as: Dim B(0 To 7) As Byte . This creates an 8 element array that contains 1 byte in each element. Eventually I store binary byte data in each element. I would like to convert the 8 bytes of data to a double type number later on in my code.

Comment: More info: the 8 byte array is declared as: Dim B(0 To 7) As Byte .  This creates an 8 element array that contains 1 byte in each element.  Eventually I store binary byte data in each element.  I would like to convert the 8 bytes of data to a double type number later on in my code.

Comment: I copied your comment into the question. Please add clarification as requested or added there - it's far easier for others to see instead of sifting through comments.

Comment: Have a look at this https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=24488

If this not fulfills your requirements you should mention how convertion shall work. Best with an example ByteArray() <=> Double. `(63; -13; -66; 118; -56; -76; 57; 88) <=> 1.234`